# LINQ to SQL many to many issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have three tables with the following, simplified schema:

```
Articles
    articleID
ArticleAuthors
    articleID
    authorID
Authors
    authorID
```

An Article can have more than one Author.

Given an input Article, I want to find all other articles written by the authors of the input Article.
So, if Joe and Jill write Article 1, I want all other articles written by either Joe or Jill. I need something to satisfy the following function:

```
public Article[] articlesBySameAuthors(Article article) {}
```

In SQL, I would just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles A 
INNER JOIN ArticleAuthors AA ON A.articleID = AA.articleID
WHERE AA.authorID IN (SELECT authorID FROM ArticleAuthors 
    WHERE articleID = @articleID) AND A.articleID <> @articleID;
```

But I really want to know how to do this in LINQ to SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do these help?

[Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx)

[Nested groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545974.aspx)

A literal translation would be silly -- I'd assume you have a better object structure than that. If you need more details on your specific object structure, post it.

Answer (score 0):

This pseudocode function assumes that you've acquired `articles`, `articleAuthors`, and `authors` elsewhere:

```
Article[] ArticlesBySameAuthors(Article article)
{
    return
        (from a in articles
        where a.ArticleID = article.ArticleID
        join articleAuthor in articleAuthors on a.ArticleID equals articleAuthor.ArticleID
        join author in authors on articleAuthor.AuthorID equals author.AuthorID
        select author).ToArray();
}
```

**EDIT:**

The preceding is the product of a tired mind.  Here's another go:

```
Article[] ArticlesBySameAuthors(Article article)
{
    return
        (from a in articles
        where a.ArticleID = article.ArticleID
        join articleAuthor in articleAuthors on a.ArticleID equals articleAuthor.ArticleID
        join articleAuthor2 in articleAuthors on articleAuthor.AuthorID equals articleAuthor2.AuthorID
        join article2 in articles on articleAuthor2.ArticleID = article2.ArticleID
        where article2.ArticleID != article.ArticleID
        select article2).ToArray();
}
```

Or, assuming that the `Article` type has an `Authors` collection, and vice versa, the following might do it:

```
Article[] ArticlesBySameAuthors(Article article)
{
    return
        (from author in article.Authors
        from article2 in author.Articles
        where article2.ArticleID != article.ArticleID
        select article2).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns the same article as the original multiplied by the number of authors on the original. Right off the bat, you say a.ArticleID = article.ArticleID, which will limit us to the same article as the original. At the end you say select author where I think you mean select a.

Comment: @Calvin of course you're right, I lost sight of the goal as I was creating the query.  Please see the edited post for a couple of additional approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = (
    from articleAuthor in articleAuthors 
    from article in articles 
    where articleAuthor.articleID == article.articleID 
    where (from aa in articleAuthors where aa.articleID == requested_article_id select aa.authorID).Contains( articleAuthor.authorID )
    select article).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Does the same thing as response number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line...

```
Var auth = db.ArticleAuthors.where(a=>a.Article == article).Select(Aa=>aa.author)

Var result = from aa in Db.articleauthors
              Were auth.Contains(aa.author)
    Select aa.Article
```